# How to pass arrays as parameters from Excel to Google Apps scripts?

Tags: json

I have an Excel file with more than 500 records and I want to import it to Google Sheets but since there are many records, the response time is slow.
What I want is to send them in packages through arrangements.
Is it possible that you can help me if it is possible or how the fixes are sent from Excel and how they are received in the Google Apps scripts?

Thanks in advance

I have passed record by record and yes it does but since there are more than 5000 records the response time is slow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.